# Double for loop to add multiple subplots on same figure

Tags: python, plot, cluster-analysis, data-mining, subplot

I am working with a clustering analysis problem. My goal is to create a double for loop which changes the numbers of clusters (3 different values for clusters) as well as cycling between the three linkage types per value cluster value. Then plot all of the subplots on the same figure.
I am hoping to achieve a 3x3 view of the subplots. Where each value of cluster is on the x-axis and each type of linkage correlating to the number of clusters is displayed down the y-axis.

The csv file I am working with is simply two columns with x1 and x2 values. I exluded the code where im import and read the csv file. The code I have thus far is as follows:

```
X1 = input_data.X1.values
X2 = input_data.X2.values
X = np.column_stack((X1, X2))


clusters = 4

Y_Kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = clusters)
Y_Kmeans.fit(X)
Y_Kmeans_labels = Y_Kmeans.labels_
Y_Kmeans_silhouette = metrics.silhouette_score(X, Y_Kmeans_labels, metric='sqeuclidean')

linkage_types = ['ward', 'average', 'complete']
Y_hierarchy = AgglomerativeClustering(linkage=linkage_types[0], n_clusters=clusters)
Y_hierarchy.fit(X)
Y_hierarchy_labels = Y_hierarchy.labels_
Y_hierarchy_silhouette = metrics.silhouette_score(X, Y_hierarchy_labels, 
metric='sqeuclidean')
```

I have tried this and am not getting the desired results:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=3, figsize=(15, 12))
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)
cluster = [4, 7, 10]
link = [0, 1, 2]
for i in cluster:
    for j in link:
        plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=colormap[Y_hierarchy_labels])
```

This is the output:
[image]

Comment: to display  in differet plots you has to use `axs` in `scatter(..., ax=...)`. It may need to `enumerate` `cluster` and `link` and later use `ax=axs[cluster_number*3 + link_number] `

Comment: you have to make all calculations inside `for`-loops (using `i` and `j` in `KMeans(n_clusters = i)` and `AgglomerativeClustering(linkage=linkage_types[j], n_clusters=i)`)

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems:

- you have to make calculations inside `for`-loops - and use `i`,`j` in `KMeans(n_clusters=i)` and `AgglomerativeClustering(linkage=linkage_types[j], n_clusters=i)`
- you have to `enumerate()` `cluster` and `link` in `for`-loops to get `ax = axs[number_cluster, number_link]` and draw `ax.scatter()`

---

Minimal working code with random data.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=3, figsize=(15, 12))
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)

cluster = [4, 7, 10]
link = [0, 1, 2]

for number_cluster, i in enumerate(cluster):

    # Y_Kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=i)
    # ... code ...

    for number_link, j in enumerate(link):

        # Y_hierarchy = gglomerativeClustering(linkage=linkage_types[j], n_clusters=i)
        # ... code ...

        X = np.random.rand(3+j, 3+i)
        print(X[:, 0], X[:, 1])

        ax = axs[number_cluster, number_link]

        ax.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], )
        ax.set_title(f'cluster: {i}, link: {j}')

plt.show()
```

[image]